# Wordpress .htaccess RewriteRule

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, rule

does someone know why the imprint rewrite rule does not work?
It does not show the imprint-custom page.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^imprint/(.*)$ imprint-custom/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```